# AngularJS parse JSON data with scope variable

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to parse JSON in AngularJS. I use `$stateParams` in this controller

```
 rerunApp.controller('rerunCategoryListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
     var stpNameCat = $stateParams.nameCat;
             $http.get(JSON URI).success(function (data, status) {
                  var response = data.Items.stpNameCat;
                  console.log(response);
             });
    });
```

My JSON is below.

```
{
   cacheFileUpdate: 1435651202,
 - Items: {
       + newsProgram: [...],
       + entertainProgram: [...],
       + documentaryProgram: [...],
       + benefitProgram: [...],
       + kidsProgram: [...],
       + dramaProgram: [...],
       + oldProgram: [...],
       + etcProgram: [...]
   }
}
```

When I run this app. I want to get item in each `Items` such as `$stateParams` is newsProgram, output is item in newsProgram. But it error at `data.Items.stpNameCat`. How can I fix it or have some method ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key is a variable, you use `data.Items[stpNameCat]` to access it instead of `data.Items.stpNameCat`.

I think you should pass the category to the server in `$http` and have it return the data you need only. But that is your design choice.